Upgrading spring boot version from 3.2.3 to 3.2.6 making build fail in bamboo giving PluginIncompatibleException
I upgraded spring boot project from 3.2.3 to 3.2.6
It started giving issues in making build in bamboo with  PluginIncompatibleException
Error is as below:
org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.1.2:deploy-file (default-cli) on project spring-upgrade: The plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.1.2 requires Maven version 3.6.3 -> [Help 1]
ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli -
ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli -
ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginIncompatibleException

pom.xml:
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>

   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.5</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

It's asking to use maven 3.6.3 but I see 3.2.5 as maven-plugin latest version in maven repository.
In local development environment, build is successful but on bamboo it's showing error and making build fail.

For the latest Maven version check here: https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html or https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.apache.maven/apache-maven/versions also you should keep the version for spring boot maven plugin in synch ... while using the parent you can omit the version... mvnrepository is not official nor up-to-date

it is not the maven plugin version but the maven Version itself that needs to be upgraded. From Spring-Boot Version 3.2.6 the maven installed on your machine that does the build needs to be 3.6.3+
The reason it works on your local machine is because locally you have a higher maven version installed - you can check you version with mvn -v.
Latest maven version is 3.9.7 as of this moment - see here
